# How to get max element from list in Jinja2 (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I use Flask and Jinja2. Now, I need to set value for some `foo` variable to zero if `bar` is negative, otherwise leave it unchanged. There are several approaches, but I'd like to make something like:

```
foo = max(0, bar)
```

The problem is that I can't find `max` filter in Jinja2. To resolve this issue I use:

```
{% set foo = [0, request.args.get('bar')|int - 25]|sort|last %}
```

So the questions are:
1. Are there any `max`-like filters in Jinja2?
2. If no, then should I create a custom one?
3. And what about approach that I've used?

Comment: `{% set foo = 0 if arg < 0 else arg %}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably not. I couldn't find it in their documentation.
2. Python already has a native `max()` function, returning maximum of a list.
3. I would suggest a simple if statement. Set foo to 0 and if bar - 25 is positive, set foo to that. Perhaps more readable that way.